# Lag when switching base layer triggered by zoom event

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I can switch between base layers fluently via button click events, but when i do the the same controlled by zoom level thresholds, i get a delay of about three seconds while the previous base layer stays visible and no further zooming action is possible. In the following example this lag appears when zooming in after page loaded. You can reproduce the problem on [my real project website](http://www.riocaramel.tk) when zooming out and in just on the beginning.

```
var geogr = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"); 
var google = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); 
var west = -2.30;
var east = -1.92;
var north = 37.87;
var south = 37.65;
var extent = new OpenLayers.Bounds(west, south, east, north).transform(geogr,google);
var center = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-2.134946,37.768344).transform(geogr,google);


map = new OpenLayers.Map("map",{
    restrictedExtent: extent,
    displayProjection: geogr,
    tileManager: null,
    transitionEffect: null,
    zoomMethod: null,
    controls:[
    new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
    new OpenLayers.Control.Scale(),
    new OpenLayers.Control.Zoom(),
    new OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults()
    ]
});


 var OSM = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM(
 "OSM", "http://a.tile.thunderforest.com/landscape/${z}/${x}/${y}.png",{
    isBaseLayer: true,
    visibility: true
});

var cycle = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM(
 "cycle", "http://a.tile.opencyclemap.org/cycle/${z}/${x}/${y}.png",{
    isBaseLayer: false,
    visibility: false
});


var aoi_edges = [
    new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(west, north),
    new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(east, north),
    new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(east, south),
    new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(west, south)
];


map.addLayers([OSM, cycle]);
map.setCenter(center, 12);


var currentZoomLevel = 108000; //level before zooming
map.events.register('zoomend', this, function (event) {
if ( (map.getScale() < 200000 && currentZoomLevel > 200000) || (map.getScale() > 4000 && currentZoomLevel < 4000) ) { // zoom threshold
    map.setBaseLayer(OSM);
}

 if ((map.getScale() > 200000 && currentZoomLevel < 200000) || (map.getScale() < 4000 && currentZoomLevel > 4000) ) { // zoom threshold
    map.setBaseLayer(cycle);
}
currentZoomLevel = map.getScale();
});
```

Comment: Have you tried setting transitionEffect: resize in the map options? What do you mean "controlled by zoom level thresholds" as a means of zooming?

Comment: the resize method does not change anything. with "controlled by zoom level thresholds" i mean, that baselayer switch automatically when passing over a distinct zoom level (in contrast to the method of clicking a button where the layer change is fluent)